# Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I am trying to split my data set into train and test sets by using:

```py
for train_set, test_set in stratified.split(complete_df, complete_df["loan_condition_int"]):
    stratified_train = complete_df.loc[train_set]
    stratified_test = complete_df.loc[test_set]
```

My dataframe `complete_df` does not have any `NaN` value. I make sured it by using `complete_df.isnull().sum().max()` which returned `0`.

But I still get a warning saying:

```
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
```

And it leads to an error later. I tried to use some techniques I found online but it does not still fix it.

Comment: Either `train_set` or `test_set` contains values which are not in the index of `complete_df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should clarify what is `stratified`. I'm assuming it's a sklearn's `StratifiedShuffleSplit` object.

> my data set complete_df does not have any NAN value.

"missing labels" from the warning message don't refer to missing values, i.e. NaNs. The error is saying that `train_set` and/ or `test_set` contain values (labels) that are not present in the index of `complete_df`. That's because `.loc` performs indexing based on row (and column) labels, not row position, while `train_set` and `test_set` indicate the row numbers. So if the index of your DataFrame doesn't coincide with the integer locations of the rows, which seems the case, the warning is raised.

To select by row position, use `iloc`. This should work

```
for train_set, test_set in stratified.split(complete_df, complete_df["loan_condition_int"]):
    stratified_train = complete_df.iloc[train_set]
    stratified_test = complete_df.iloc[test_set]
```